# Is there a standard way to compare Clojure vectors in the 'conventional' way

Tags: sorting, vector, clojure

Clojure vectors have the uncommon property that when you compare them, the length of the vector is considered before any other property. In e.g. Haskell

```
Prelude> [1, 3] > [1, 2, 3]
True
```

and Ruby

```
1.9.3p392 :003 > [1, 3] <=> [1, 2, 3]
 => 1
```

But in Clojure:

```
user=> (compare [1, 3] [1, 2, 3])
-1
```

Now you can implement the 'conventional' comparison yourself:

```
(defn vector-compare [[value1 & rest1] [value2 & rest2]]
  (let [result (compare value1 value2)]
    (cond 
      (not (= result 0)) result
      (nil? value1) 0 ; value2 will be nil as well 
      :else (recur rest1 rest2))))
```

but I expect this way of comparing vectors is so common that there is a standard way to achieve this. Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `compare` function compares 2 things if they implement interface `java.lang.Comparable`. Vector in Clojure implement this interface as shown at [this](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentVector.java#L397) link, basically it check the length first. There is no core function which does what you want so you will have to roll your own function.

Other thing I would like to mention is that the haskell version is basically comparing lists (not vector) and it is not efficient to calculate list length which make sense to avoid length while comparing lists where as vector length calculation is O(1) operation and hence it make sense to check the length first.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
(first (filter (complement zero?) (map compare [1 3] [1 2 3])))
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't return the expected result for vectors of unequal size, e.g. [1 2] and [1 2 3]. In other languages (or at least: Haskell and Ruby) the longest vector will be considered larger when they have equal prefixes. A shorter version is nice, but I'm mostly wondering whether a version exists in the core or standard libraries.

Comment: Granted,  but  perhaps  in  writing  your  own  function  you  could  leverage some  of the  core  functions I  used.